# Shared preferences logging system in android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I searched in stackoverflow and i could not find anything like this. I want to make a logging system like registration and login. But the following code does not work when clicked LogIN. There is probably error in the if logic. please help'.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.asifsabir.sharedpref;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    EditText ed1,ed2;
    Button b1,b2,b3;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
    public static final String email = "emailKey";
    public static final String password = "passwordKey";
    public static final String safety = "safetyKey";
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences2;
       //
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email  = ed1.getText().toString();
                String password  = ed2.getText().toString();

                 if(sharedpreferences.getString(password,"").equals(password))
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Logged on Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email  = ed1.getText().toString();
                String password  = ed2.getText().toString();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();


                editor.putString(email,email);
                editor.putString(password,password);
                editor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Thanks! Signed up",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }



}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Shared Preference \n     login system"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="35dp" />


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="email id: " />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="password: " />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="forgot password?"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Another problem is : I registered with email:  asif and password :12345     and also email: david pasword: 555     but I can login using email : asif and password: 555  ;how that can be solved?

Comment: So, your issue is that any combination of the email and password logs you in, correct?

Comment: You are using local and global variables for email and password with the same name, instead change de globals to emailKey, passwordKeyand here: sharedpreferences.getString(password,"").equals(password)), change to sharedpreferences.getString(passwordKey,"").equals(password))

Comment: made a little edit to my answer. let me know how it goes.

Comment: Look at this. I tried as you have said, but it does not work. @danilo silva

Comment: Change here too: editor.putString(emailKey,email);
                editor.putString(passwordKey,password);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with you understanding of `SharedPref`. It stores key-value pairs. If you use the same key to store all the emails, you would still need a way to correlate between the username and the password. One way to achieve this could be to do something like this:

```
String email = ed1.getText().toString();
String password = ed2.getText().toString();
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

editor.putString(email, password);
editor.commit();
```

Then, retrieval would be as simple as...

```
String email = ed1.getText().toString();
String password = ed2.getText().toString();
if(sharedpreferences.getString(email,"").equals(password))
    ** LOG USER IN **
```

An alternative way is to store all emails with the same key, and all passwords with the same key. Here, you would need to do something to ensure that emails and the passwords are connected to each other. One way could be to append email to the end of the password, and then save it.

```
String email = ed1.getText().toString();
String password = ed2.getText().toString();

password += email;

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString(this.email,email);
editor.putString(this.password,password);
editor.commit();
```

Instead of using `getString(..)` you would now need to use [[`getStringSet`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29)].

**Edit**.

It would also be a good idea to change the names of these 2 fields.

```
public static final String email = "emailKey";          // to emailKey
public static final String password = "passwordKey";    // to passwordKey
```

This will avoid confusion with the contents of the `EditText` boxes.

Comment: So if i type in a random username, and a blank password when logging in, i can connect regardless of registration? ;)

Comment: @Doomsknight Haha. I was expecting someone to catch onto that. I simply focused on showing the way this can be done, not the validity of the method. Storing emails and passwords as plaintext is not a good idea anyway. But, yes. Your point is something the OP should keep in mind during implementation.

Comment: :p Felt i should raise is so that you and the OP are aware. +1 for a good overall answer.

Comment: @Doomsknight Appreciate it, buddy. If you want to make any changes/modifications, please feel free to go for it.

Answer (score 0):

//LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
        /*Componentes gráficos*/
        Button btnLogin;
        TextView txtOmitir;
        EditText etUser, etPass;

        /*Variables globales*/
        int value, valueLogin, servicesLogin;
        Intent intent;
        String favoriteService;
        String username, password;
        private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        private SharedPreferences prefs;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.layoutlogin);
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);


            prefs = getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = prefs.edit();

            Bundle num = getIntent().getExtras();

            if (num != null) {
                servicesLogin = num.getInt("serviceslogin");
            }
            favoriteService = prefs.getString("valueService", "");


            etUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUser);
            etPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPass);


            btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
            txtOmitir = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOmitir);

        }

        public void btnClickLogin(View view) {
            username = etUser.getText().toString();
            password = etPass.getText().toString();

            if (username.equals("") || password.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Introduzca sus llaves",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            } else {

                intent = new Intent();
                editor.putString("username", username);
                editor.putString("password", password);
                editor.commit();


                    intent.setClass(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                Toast.makeText(this, "Log-In Completado..",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }//btnClick




    public void btnClickOmitir(View view) {

            intent = new Intent();

            editor.putString("username", "");
            editor.putString("password", "");
            editor.commit();
            intent.setClass(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }//class
```

//**layoutlogin.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:id="@+id/imgLogin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etUser"
            android:hint="username"
            android:maxLength="16"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text="root" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etPass"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:hint="password"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text="masterkey" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Recordar"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Empleado"
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

            <Switch
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/switch1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:checked="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Alumno"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Log in"
                android:onClick="btnClickLogin"
                android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button

                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="OMITIR"
                android:onClick="btnClickOmitir"
                android:id="@+id/txtOmitir"
                android:textColor="#1619ef"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

//**you can check with it**

```
prefs = getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias",    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String email = ed1.getText().toString();    
String password = ed2.getText().toString();

                               passwordLogin=prefs.getString("password","");
                               userLogin = prefs.getString("username", "");

                               editor = prefs.edit();

                               if (userLogin.equals(email) &&     passwordLogin.equals(password )) {
                               //do something     //Login succesfull
                               }
```

Comment: and why exactly does this work? you haven't even marked any changes! are people supposed to go through the wall of code?

Comment: Nope, that does not help, I wanted to check if the login input was as per the password combination what was signed up before. @Cristofer Marin